# Set the working path correctly

Tags: java, unix, process, processbuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pwd");
pb.directory(new File("/server1/work/uz/rt/adapt/0/"));
Process s = pb.start();
```

I expected the output to be `/server1/work/uz/rt/adapt/0/`, but instead it's:

```
/work/uz/rt/adapt/0/
```

`/work/uz/rt/adapt/0/` and `/server1/work/uz/rt/adapt/0/` are equivalent (mounted at the same place,/work/.. is correct path and /server1/work/.. is the mounted one ), but I need to work under `/server1/work/uz/rt/adapt/0/` because some other servers only work through that path.

How can I make `/server1/work/uz/rt/adapt/0/` the current path?

IN OTHER WORDS

why public ProcessBuilder directory(File directory)
converts directory into canonical File. How can I use absolute File Path??

I also tried the hack soln'

```
        pb.directory(new File("/asr1/work/oguz/rt/adaptMLLR2/0/"){
             public File getCanonicalFile(){
                 return this.getAbsoluteFile();
             }
             public String getCanonicalPath() {
                 return this.getAbsolutePath();
             }

        });
```

which didnt work as well.

I resolved my problem by adding cd /server1/.. line in to the bash script.. and deleted pd.directory(..) line. BUT this problem (why I cant use pd.directory(..) with absolutePath ) is not answered yet...???

Comment: Is server1 a shared network resource?

Comment: It is physical server. other servers can access through the path /server1/.. . There are shared files, folders in server1..

Comment: Have you tried running `pwd -L`?  I believe `pwd` by default dereferences symlinks.

Comment: pwd isnt the problem. it is there for only debug purpose. When I call from server2 it says I cannot find the path /work/.. , because it must be /server1/work/.. . the path /work/.. is not available to server2 but the symbolic referance /server1/work/..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a shell's `cd` utility seems an appropriate solution. An alternative would be to set the `PWD` environment variable to the pathname with symlinks, but this is ugly unless you get `ProcessBuilder` to do it for you automatically.

Note that shells ignore `PWD` if it is not an absolute pathname for the current directory, asking the system for a absolute pathname without symlinks instead.